# How to replace words in shapes all at once (without looping through the shapes) in Word using VBA

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word

I have a list containing around 1000 word pairs for replacement. By looping through the shapes I have to loop through the word pairs again and again. To make it run faster I tried to select all shapes before execute the replacement but it didn't work. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

relevant part of current code (the pairs are stored in a list named key() and a dictionary named oDic):

```
With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchByte = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchFuzzy = False
End With
shape_num = ActiveDocument.Shapes.count
On Error GoTo errhandler

For i = 1 To shape_num
    If ActiveDocument.Shapes(i).TextFrame.HasText Then
        ActiveDocument.Shapes(i).Select
        For j = 1 To lexicon_num
            SrcText = key(j)
            With Selection.Find
                .Text = SrcText
                .Replacement.Text = oDic.Item(SrcText)
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            End With
        Next j
    End If
    continue_shape:
Next i
exit sub
errhandler:
Err.Clear
Resume continue_shape
```

Comment: You may want to add your current code? As for your question, I don't think there's another way aside looping. That is AFAIK.

Comment: What do you mean in 'shapes'?

Comment: @user3165438 text boxes, squares, arrows, etc.

Comment: @Noir, Well, Each shape has a particular equivalent text, like "Ball" to an arrow and "Balloon" to textbox?

Comment: @user3165438 Nope, some of the shapes contain texts in them, and I want to replace words in the texts according to a word-pair list.

Comment: @user3165438 e.g. let's say there is a square containing a sentence "This test requires a lot of data" and my word-pair list contains "test <-> テスト" and "data <-> データ", then I want the sentence in the square to be "This テスト requires a lot of データ" after the replacement.

Comment: I can share a Word Find and Replace method that works in C#. Will it help you?

Comment: What you should realize is that even if there was a way to do it "without looping", looping would still be occuring behind the scenes. If you want to hide the looping, encapsulate the assignments into a function or hide the details inside a class.

Comment: As for tips to optimize the speed of your code, try using `Replace` instead of the more advanced find & replace functionality you are currently using. I would guess that the setup and tear down cost of using `Find` for such a small amount of text would add up very quickly.  If you want to optimize it even more, you could implement a trie data structure to store your key/value pairs and then parse through the shape strings yourself. As you process each word, you attempt to navigate down the trie letter by letter. If it's there, you replace, if not, you leave it as is in the output.

Comment: @user3165438 I'm afraid that will not help much since I do not know any C# and only intend to make my current VBA code run faster. Thank you all the same!

Comment: @Blackhawk Thanks for your input! As for the `Replace` strategy, I guess by that it will be hard to retain the font (names, colors, etc.) variety (if any) of the text in one shape. The only workaround that I can think of is firstly record all font information character by character, then keep track whenever the replacement causes length change, and write all the font information back in the final step. (I'm not sure whether that will eat up all the time saved by using `Replace`.) If I was wrong, please point out. As for the `trie` strategy, that sounds very promising  and I will try it.

Answer (score 3):

Please note that the answer to your specific question is: **No, it is not possible to replace words in shapes all at once (without looping through the shapes) in Word using VBA**

However, my impression is that what you are actually interested in is the more general question of how to optimize your code.  Below is one solution.

I suggested implementing a `Trie` in the comments, but after further consideration, I think the built-in `Scripting.Dictionary` object is more than sufficient for what you need.

I propose that you load up a `Scripting.Dictionary` with the words you want to find (as the Key) and replace (as the Value).  You can loop once through the words of each shape and check the `Scripting.Dictionary` to see if it exists.  If it does, replace it; if not, leave it alone.

I created a Rectangle with the text "This shape has the word "**find**" in it." where "find" is bolded and red.  I ran a test against it replacing "find" with "replace" and the formatting is kept.

Here is the sample code:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim dictFindReplace As Scripting.Dictionary

    Set dictFindReplace = New Scripting.Dictionary

    'Add all your words to the dictionary here
    dictFindReplace.Add "find", "replace"

    'Loop through all the shapes
    For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count

        'If the shape has text
        If ActiveDocument.Shapes(i).TextFrame.HasText Then
            With ActiveDocument.Shapes(i).TextFrame.TextRange.Words
                'Loop through each word. This method preserves formatting.
                For j = 1 To .Count

                    'If a word exists in the dictionary, replace the text of it, but keep the formatting.
                    If dictFindReplace.Exists(.Item(j).Text) Then
                        .Item(j).Text = dictFindReplace.Item(.Item(j).Text)
                    End If
                Next
            End With
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't, of course, have to add all 1000 word find/replace pairs within the code. You could load them from an external source like a text file or an Excel document.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The problem with this method seems to be that for Chinese, Japanese and other languages in which words are not separated by spaces, one can not get words parsed by .Textrange.Words. Besides, even in the case of English, some pairs are actually phrases rather than single words.

Comment: I was afraid of that :(  In that case, the Trie and character by character parsing is still probably the best option.  If I get the chance, I'll take a swing at it... if anyone else wants to cannibalize my answer to make their own, feel free!