# How to change multiple phrases, within multiple word documents with help of python script?

Tags: python, ms-word, ms-office

cause recently I'm getting a lot of repetive work, I'm working how could I automate it, so I've decided to start with python. I have to refill documents, often replacing certain pharses. I've managed to find ready script for python, but it can change only one word within multiple documents. I'm trying to modify it so it works with a list of words, but actually I'm getting nowhere. Any help or hints?

I came with solution to put list inside the loop and iterate, with for function for two arguments
but now I'm getting Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\t.lachowicz\Desktop\PYTHON\textreplace2.py", line 29, in 
for find_str, replace_with in doc_file:
TypeError: 'WindowsPath' object is not iterable

```
from pathlib import Path  # core python module

import win32com.client  # pip install pywin32

# Path settings
current_dir = Path(__file__).parent if "__file__" in locals() else Path.cwd()
input_dir = current_dir / "input"
output_dir = current_dir / "output"
output_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)





# Open Word
word_app = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Word.Application")
word_app.Visible = False
word_app.DisplayAlerts = False


for doc_file in Path(input_dir).rglob("*.doc*"):

    # Find & replace
    find_str = ("Materialdatenblätter", "1129")
    replace_with = ("Material Technical Data", "2400")
    wd_replace = 2  # 2=replace all occurences, 1=replace one occurence, 0=replace no occurences
    wd_find_wrap = 1  # 2=ask to continue, 1=continue search, 0=end if search range is reached
    
    for find_str, replace_with in doc_file:
            # Open each document and replace string
            word_app.Documents.Open(str(doc_file))
            # API documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.find.execute
            word_app.Selection.Find.Execute(
                FindText=find_str,
                ReplaceWith=replace_with,
                Replace=wd_replace,
                Forward=True,
                MatchCase=True,
                MatchWholeWord=False,
                MatchWildcards=True,
                MatchSoundsLike=False,
                MatchAllWordForms=False,
                Wrap=wd_find_wrap,
                Format=True,
            )

            # -- Replace str in shapes
        # VBA SO reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26266598
            # Loop through all the shapes
            for i in range(word_app.ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count):
                if word_app.ActiveDocument.Shapes(i + 1).TextFrame.HasText:
                            words = word_app.ActiveDocument.Shapes(i + 1).TextFrame.TextRange.Words
                            # Loop through each word. This method preserves formatting.
                            for j in range(words.Count):
                            # If a word exists, replace the text of it, but keep the formatting.
                            if word_app.ActiveDocument.Shapes(i + 1).TextFrame.TextRange.Words.Item(j + 1).Text == find_str:
                                        word_app.ActiveDocument.Shapes(i + 1).TextFrame.TextRange.Words.Item(j + 1).Text = replace_with

# Save the new file
output_path = output_dir / f"{doc_file.stem}_replaced{doc_file.suffix}"
word_app.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(str(output_path))
word_app.ActiveDocument.Close(SaveChanges=False)
word_app.Application.Quit()
```

I tried to replace find_str variable, to set it as function, and iterate the main replace function, to work with list or dictionary. I have been expecting for this script to iterrate it for multiple arguments, and replace multiple words if it finds it. But apparently this is bit to hard for beginner, so any hint would be helpful, thanks in advance